# Count valid values per user

Tags: t-sql, count

I have a table with a list of values. -1 is a blank value:

```
 ID    FieldType1A FieldType1B FieldType2A FieldType2B Person
  1             15          14          10          -1      1
  2             16          -1          12          10      1
  3             17          -1           5           6      1
  4              6          -1           7          -1      2
 ...
```

So the result should be:

```
 Person      FieldType1     FieldType2
      1               4              5
      2               1              1
```

there is a users table with a list of user IDs, would there be a way of iterating over that list of values to generate the person list in the result set (0 for the field types being perfectly valid as it is merely counts)? I think the answer to [T-SQL Column Values Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085756/t-sql-column-values-count) is a step in the direction I'm attempting to go, but unsure how to combine columns that are the same (the A/Bs allow for a list of answers). That and I'm interested in combining all valid values as not attempting to count the number of each valid response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to change all non-negative-one values to 1, and -1 values to 0, and then sum them up.

```
SELECT Person, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN FieldType1A <> -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FieldType1B <> -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FieldType1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FieldType2A <> -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FieldType2B <> -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FieldType2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Person
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Runs a lot quicker than the C# code I was using in place of it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Person, 
count(nullif(FieldType1A, -1)) + count(nullif(FieldType1B, -1)) as FieldType1, 
count(nullif(FieldType2A, -1)) + count(nullif(FieldType2B, -1)) as FieldType2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY person
```

Comment: Oooh, +1 for `NULLIF`; I always forget about that function.